# Proving mean of sample minimum of U[0,1] is 1/(n+1) without calculus

Tags: alternative-proof, order-statistics

Let $U : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \nrightarrow \mathrm{dist}[\mathbb{R}]$ denote the parametrized family of uniform distributions where $U(a, b)$ is the uniform distribution with minimum $a$ and maximum $b$ . $U$ is a partial function defined whenever $a \lt b$ .

Let's define $Y_1, Y_2, \dots Y_n$ as an $n$-element sample drawn from $U(0,1)$ . Let $Y_{(1)}$ denote the sample minimum. Let $f$ denote the pdf of the sample minimum of $n$ elements drawn from $U(0, 1)$ and let $F$ denote the corresponding cdf.

I want to demonstrate that its expected value is $\frac{1}{n+1}$ in a way that's as simple as possible, ideally without using calculus.

$$ \mathrm{E}[Y_{(1)}] = \frac{1}{n+1} $$

Here's one way to do it, which does use calculus:

$$ \mathrm{E}[Y_{(1)}] \tag{1}$$

use known formula for expectation in terms of cdf

$$ \int_{s=0}^\infty 1-F(s) \mathrm{d}s \tag{2}$$

$F(s) = 1$ when $s \ge 1$ .

$$ \int_{s=0}^{1} 1 - F(s) \mathrm{d}s \tag{3} $$

$F(t)$ is the probability that the sample minimum is less than $t$.

$$ \int_{s=0}^{1} 1 - \mathbb{P}[Y_1 \le s \lor \cdots \lor Y_n \le s] \mathrm{d}s \tag{4} $$

$1-\mathbb{P}[\psi]$ is $\mathbb{P}[\lnot \psi]$ .

$$ \int_{s=0}^{1} \mathbb{P}[Y_1 \ge s \land \cdots \land Y_n \ge s] \mathrm{d}s \tag{5} $$

replace integrand with product.

$$ \int_{s=0}^{1} (1-s)^n \mathrm{d}s \tag{6} $$

change variable $ t = 1-s $ and swap bounds of integral.

$$ \int_{t=0}^{1} t^n \mathrm{d}t \tag{7} $$

simplify

$$ \frac{1}{n+1} \tag{8} $$

ΟΕΔ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a circle of length $1$, and choose $n+1$ points independently and uniformly on it. Cut the circle at the first point, and unwrap to the interval $[0,1]$; the remaining $n$ points are distributed uniformly and independently on that interval. Now, those points cut $[0,1]$ into $n+1$ subintervals, in order. What's the expected length of each of them? Well, pull back to the circle - there was nothing special about us cutting at the first point. Cut at one of the other points, and we cycle the subintervals around, while keeping the same picture of $n$ uniform points after the cut. Thus, the lengths of all $n+1$ subintervals are identically distributed. In particular, they have the same mean. As their sum is $1$, the mean of each must be $\frac1{n+1}$ by linearity of expectation. Done.

This also works to calculate the expected value of all of the other order statistics; the $k$th smallest has expected value $\frac{k}{n+1}$.